# Redefinition of _InterlockedAdd64

Tags: c, mingw-w64, wdk, wdm

I'm making a simple kernel mode driver with MinGW-W64 7.1.0 (seh, posix) in Code::Blocks. I'm compiling with built-in DDK headers in "include/ddk". But build fails with that error:

```
||=== Build: Release in test_driver (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\ddk\wdm.h|361|error: redefinition of '_InterlockedAdd64'|
C:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\ddk\wdm.h|376|note: in expansion of macro 'InterlockedAdd64'|
C:\mingw64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\psdk_inc\intrin-impl.h|1035|note: previous definition of '_InterlockedAdd64' was here|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Same code compiles fine with TDM-GCC 64 bit, but it uses a really old version of GCC, 5.1.0.

I tried older versions of MinGW-W64 with different threading models and exceptions with no luck.

Probably I'm missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I love MinGW and I use it every day, but for kernel mode stuff I would just use whatever VC++ version the official DDK provides, especially since all the information I can find about using MinGW to compile drivers is mostly unofficial - as in, not even from the MinGW guys.

Comment: I don't want to use Visual Studio or another heavy IDE, and that's why I use MinGW for Windows driver development. Compiling drivers in command line with only WDK would really good. For "normal" program development, I love MinGW, too. @MatteoItalia

Comment: Who talked about an IDE? The official DDK last time I checked provided just the VC++ *compiler*, you can use whatever editor you like.

Comment: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/windows-driver-kit says I should install Visual Studio, also WDK installation says it doesn't include any compiler or linker. How can I use WDK and VC++ without Visual Studio?

Comment: Hm, this changed quite recently, previously the DDK included the compiler and everything needed to build drivers without much else. Still, you can just use the VC++ *compiler* without actually coding into the IDE and build stuff from the command line as specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/develop/building-a-driver).

Comment: I've opened [a bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/776/) against `mingw-w64`.

Answer (score 2):

I added this in my C file:

`#define __INTRINSIC_DEFINED__InterlockedAdd64`

Seems like a clash between intrin-impl.h and wdm.h. I hope someone from the mingw community can solve this :)